# Why does Python automatically encode hex in strings as UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have been using python to do ascii-to-binary translations and kept running into issues with parsing the result. Eventually I thought to look at what the Python commands were generating.

There seems to be a rouge `0xc2` inserted in the output (for example):

```
$ python -c 'print("\x80")' | xxd
00000000: c280 0a                                  ...
```

Indeed this happens regardless of where such bytes are used:

```
$ python -c 'print("Test\x80Test2\x81")' | xxd
00000000: 5465 7374 c280 5465 7374 32c2 810a       Test..Test2...
```

On a hunch, I poked around at [UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=0x) and sure enough, `U+0080` is encoded as `0xc2 0x80`. Apparently, Python takes the liberty of assuming by `\x80` I *actually* meant the encoding for `U+0080`. Is there  a way to change this default behavior or otherwise explicitly dictate my intention of including the singlar byte `0x80` and not the UTF encoding?

`Python 3.6.2`

Comment: Are you aware of pythons `bytes` type? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 does the right thing of inserting a character into a `str` which is string of characters, not a byte sequence.

UTF8 is the default encoding. If you need to insert a byte, a different encoding where that character is represented as a byte is needed.

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=iso-8859-1 python3 -c 'print("\x80")' | xxd
00000000: 800a
```

> PYTHONIOENCODING
>
> If this is set before running the interpreter, it overrides the encoding used for stdin/stdout/stderr, in the syntax
>   encodingname:errorhandler. Both the encodingname and the :errorhandler
>   parts are optional and have the same meaning as in str.encode().

Comment: Changing the global encoding for strings is a (quite inelegant) global solution to a local problem. If OP is building a bytes sequence and not a character sequence he should use `byte` objects and not `str` objects (or, of anything, encode just the relevant `str` objects to Latin1 using the `encode` method).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, but I do not understand this case like a "local problem". The OP asked for changing the default and mentioned that ascii-to-binary translations are what he is using the program for.

Comment: Fair enough, although the OP isn't _really_ doing ascii-to-binary translation, since `b'\x80'` isn't legal ASCII.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Such pendantism. Sure, `\x80` is not legal printable ASCII, but it was clear what my intentions were. Perhaps _hex to binary_ is a better description.

Comment: @sherrellbc Perhaps it is a bit pedantic, but when you're doing stuff with character encodings it pays to be pedantic. ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to output raw bytes in Python 3 you shouldn't be using the `print` function, since it's for outputting text in your default encoding. Instead, you can use `sys.stdout.buffer.write`.

ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, so if your so-called ASCII contains characters like `b'\x80'` it's not legal ASCII. Perhaps your data is actually encoded with iso-8859-1, aka latin-1, or it could be the closely-related Windows variant [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). To do this kind of thing correctly you need to determine the actual encoding that was used to create the data.

If you want to output `"Test\x80Test2\x81"` and have the hex dump look like this:

```
00000000  54 65 73 74 80 54 65 73  74 32 81                 |Test.Test2.|
```

You can do

```
import sys
s = "Test\x80Test2\x81"
sys.stdout.buffer.write(s.encode('latin1'))
```

This works because Latin-1 is a subset of Unicode. Here's a quick demo:

```
import binascii

a = ''.join([chr(i) for i in range(256)])
b = a.encode('latin1')
print(binascii.hexlify(b))
```

**output**

```
b'000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabacadaeafb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9babbbcbdbebfc0c1c2c3c4c5c6c7c8c9cacbcccdcecfd0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9dadbdcdddedfe0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9eaebecedeeeff0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff'
```

However, if you're actually working with binary data then you shouldn't be storing it in text strings in the first place, you should be using `bytes`, or possibly `bytearray`. The sane way to produce the `b` bytes string from my previous example is to do

```
b = bytes(range(256))
```

And if you have a `bytes` object like `b"Test\x80Test2\x81"` you can dump those bytes to stdout with

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"Test\x80Test2\x81")
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. There is no data storage. My use-case was to generate a string of ASCII and non-printables and then pipe it directly to stdin of a program under test.

Comment: @sherrellbc No worries. In that case you definitely don't want to use text strings for this, do everything with `bytes` and `bytearray`s.

Comment: @sherrellbc And if the program that you're piping this binary data to is a Python 3 program then you should get it to read the data from `sys.stdin.buffer`, don't read it by calling `input`, because that expects text strings.